# Finding K combination of three items with minimum product

Tags: arrays, algorithm, math, combinations

While solving a problem I came to a situation where I have to find first k products of combination of three items from given array of positive numbers , such that product should be minimum.
Given Array `A`, with size `n` , find fist `k` products of three different items of array with minimum value efficiently. Lets call that `MP` such that

```
MP[i] = A[j]* A[l]*A[m]
```

where `i<K, j!=l!=m`and `k<n`

What I have tried at that point of time is get all possible products and then sort them to get first k products. But I know this is not efficient as first O(N^3) for finding all combinations product and then at least O(NlogN) for sorting N^3 combinations. So in my case the array size was not large, But I am wondering how to solve the same problem more efficiently.

Comment: Can the array contain negative numbers??

Comment: Array contains  positive numbers only.

Answer (score 3):

The problem with other solutions is that their **greedy choice** is non-optimal.

A simple **priority queue** based solution will give the optimal solution to this problem. *min_product* is the function which delivers the required array and the map is used to keep track of already seen tuples. I have used a simple stl priority queue.

```
//// Asume the vector a(size>=3) is sorted    
std::vector<int> a;
struct triplet{
    int i,j,k;
};

long long value(triplet& p1){
    return (long long)a[p1.i]*(long long)a[p1.j]*a[p1.k];
}

struct CompareTriplet {
    bool operator()(triplet const & p1, triplet const & p2) {
        return value(p1) > value(p2);
    }
};

void push_heap(std::priority_queue<triplet, std::vector<triplet> pq, CompareTriplet>& pq,triplet &t,std::vector<triplet>& m;){
    if (m.find(t)!=m.end()){
        m[t]=1;
        pq.push(t);
    }
}

std::vector<long long> min_product(int k){

    sort(a.begin(), a.end()); // sort if not sorted.
    int n=a.size();

    std::unodered_map<triplet,bool> m;
    std::vector<long long> MP(k);

    std::priority_queue<triplet, std::vector<triplet>, CompareTriplet> pq;

    push_heap(pq,triplet{0,1,2},m);

    for(int i=0; !pq.empty() and i<k;i++){
        auto tp = pq.top(); pq.pop();
        MP[i]=value(tp);

        if (tp.i+1<tp.j){
            push_heap(pq,triplet{tp.i+1,tp.j,tp.k},m);
        }
        if (tp.j+1<tp.k){
            push_heap(pq,triplet{tp.i,tp.j+1,tp.k},m);
        }
        if (tp.k+1<n){
            push_heap(pq,triplet{tp.i,tp.j,tp.k+1},m);
        }
    }
    return MP
}
```

**Complexity**:

If the array is not sorted, then making it sorted is the bottleneck here. Actually at any time, we need top i (

***For a sorted given array.***

Since there can be at most 2*k elements in the heap and O(k) number of operations(both heap and map) are done for getting each element of MP. So, running time complexity is **O( k*log(k) )**.

And yes, it is independent of n.

Comment: That's a variation of the algorithm that I suggested in my answer in that it respects that a greedy choice is not required. Unfortunately, it assumes that the `A` is sorted, which was not a requirement in the question. The sorting adds `O(n log(n))` complexity, and is far from optimal when `A` is not sorted. Sorting `A` is not required for the solution (see my answer).

Comment: @NicolaiEhemann, In my algorithm, I do not actually need to sort the elements of a initially in the beginning. I will create another heap from array and then remove min and use it when it is actually required [ith remove_top will be called when k==i ] . This way my complexity will still be a function of k. I will update the code for that.

Comment: Well, if the input array is not sorted before, you will definitely at least have to look at every element of A to find the smallest, so the complexity has to be a function of `n`. If A is sorted before, the complexity is only dependent on `k` and my algorithm is worse than yours.

Comment: oh I got it complexity, will depend on n in any case.

Comment: As it turned out, my solution was plain wrong. Would be nice to have a more formal description of yours with the correct complexity.